# How to make carousel fixed overlay for Bootstrap 4.1?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to carousel overlay for Bootstrap 4.1 but .carousel-control-prev-icon and carousel-control-next-icon not working. how can i run icon? Not for each slide element. Just one overlay but over slides.
Below html code;

```
<!-- Start Banner-->
<section id="banner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="bg-overlay">try fixed overlay</div>
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="resources/images/image-1.jpg" alt="image slide">
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="resources/images/image-2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="resources/images/image-3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Önceki</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Sonraki</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Below css code;

```
.bg-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css file you can overwrite Bootstraps default classes. You can directly target both arrows css to give them a larger `z-index` value.

Example:

```
.carousel-control-prev {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

and

```
.carousel-control-next {
    right: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

This will bring the arrows above your overlay and make them clickable.

[Example Codepen](https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/roZObo)

Comment: As you said you tried to have worked :) Thank you bro.

Answer (score 1):

In this example next and previous buttons has an overlay style:

////////////////////////

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

////////////////////////

Comment: Yes I know my solution was like the one I tried to ask. Thank you :)